Getting HTTP request failed: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url - When running Http Cloud function from Cloud composer DAG
I am running a DAG in Cloud Composer version 3 to trigger an HTTP cloud function on the same shared VPC. Both GCP services are using the same user-created service account. However, I'm encountering the error 'HTTP request failed: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for URL'. I have granted all necessary permissions from the host and service projects to service account as described in the following URL: :-
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-3/configure-shared-vpc
Interestingly, when I tried triggering the same HTTP cloud function inside a Compute Engine using curl command, it was successfully triggered.
curl command:- curl -m 70 -X POST Function endpoint 
-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{ }'
Adding the python code also that I am using in DAG:-

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import requests
import subprocess
import logging


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 7, 2),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'run_cloud_function_daily',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Run HTTP-based Cloud Function daily ',
    schedule='0 19 * * *',  # Cron expression for daily at 7 PM
)

# Define the URL of your HTTP-based Cloud Function endpoint
cloud_function_url = ''


# Function to fetch authorization token using gcloud and call the Cloud Function
def call_cloud_function_with_auth_token():
    try:
        # Fetch authorization token using gcloud command
        token_command = 'gcloud auth print-identity-token'
        result = subprocess.run(token_command, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
        authorization_token = result.stdout.strip()  # Get the output of the command (token)
        if authorization_token:
            print('Token Successfully retrieved',authorization_token)
        # Prepare headers with authorization token
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"bearer {authorization_token}"
        }

        # Prepare payload if needed
        payload = {}  # Replace with your JSON payload if needed

        # Make HTTP POST request to Cloud Function endpoint
        response = requests.post(cloud_function_url, headers=headers)
        
        # Check response status
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors (4xx, 5xx)

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to fetch authorization token: {e}")
        raise
        logging.info("HTTP request successful:", response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"HTTP request failed: {e}")
        raise
        print(f"Details: {e.response.text if e.response else 'No response details'}")

# Define the PythonOperator to execute the function
run_cloud_function_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='call_cloud_function_with_auth_token',
    python_callable=call_cloud_function_with_auth_token,
    dag=dag,
)

# Set task dependencies
run_cloud_function_task


Why do you use subprocess function in Python and not using the Google Cloud Client libraries? In addition, you are not sure that GCLOUD is installed on your composer worker (and it's pretty that's not!)

@guillaumeblaquiere have used subprocess just for testing the connections. Yes, We can surely use google client libraries to get access. Can you please recommend/suggest what steps should be followed to avoid Http 403 Forbidden error.

What's the configuration of your Cloud Functions? Especially did you set special parameter, like the ingress? And which permission did you give to the used service account?

@guillaumeblaquiere Right now Ingress settings - Allow all traffic in the cloud function as default.
Following permissions are granted to service account - Cloud run invoker, Cloud function invoker, Composer shared VPC agent, Service Account User. Just to test if this is permissions issue with service account, I have tried triggering by giving Owner rights to service account but same issue happened.

If you don't restrict the ingress, the VPC/SHared vpc is useless here. Are you sure about the service account used to call the Cloud Functions with your dag? Are you sure about its permissions?

@guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for pointing that. After changing the ingress to Internal, Now Http 404 Not found error coming for function endpoint. I have used same service account for function runtime execution while deploying and for composer environment. So I am assuming same must be used from airflow worker to call cloud function. Please correct if I am wrong here. Although all necessary permissions like Cloud run invoker, Cloud function invoker, Composer shared VPC agent, Service Account User are granted on service account.

In the composer section, in the GCP console, you can see in the environment configuration, the service account (3rd line). It's this one used by the workers

@guillaumeblaquiere Yes it is same as service account mentioned in details section of cloud function general information section's service account. And this have cloud run invoker access as this is gen2 function.
